# Select part of a tikz picture and reuse it in the code of another

Tags: tikz-pgf

Here is my problem, suppose you converted a pdf figure to tikz code using Inkscape. Very often, the file is long and the commands are not ordered, so that if you want to copy only 20% east of the generated figure into another tikz figure you have to waist your time on trying to find the different lines of code that are involved in this 20% of the figure.

Hence my question, how to tell latex to select a rectangular area of another tikz picture. In pseudo-code this will be.

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw[] something;
      \draw copy[only x>0.8]{anotherTikzpicture.tikz};
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Many thanks,

Comment: There is the command `\clip` which you can use, for example, to create a rectangle and use it as clipping area.

Comment: @Sigur First thank you for the quick answere. Can I use it with relative coordinates, even if the Inkscape generated tikz picture uses coordinates with an order of magnitude of 200 ?.

Comment: Hum, change coordinates could be a problem. Maybe, it is better to export the image as PDF and then you include it with `\includegraphics[]{}` and also use an option to trim/clip the image.

Comment: @Sigur, then there is a problem, line widths and fonts are scaled also which not the requirement. However, even in absolute coordinates can you please edit the code and answer to the question then I can check it as resolved. Until someone suggests a more general solution.  Using includegraphics and clip, I don't know if it works with tikzscale package.

Comment: I believe that my comment is not an answer. I even don't know if you can input some piece of TiKz code within `tikzpicture` using some command (e.g. `\input{}`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So to take the impractical route first. If you would be willing to work out the coordinates manually, you could modify the output file from Inkscape slightly, to get what you'are after. Assuming you exported as a Tikzpicture to `drawing.tikz`, the code from Inkscape will look something like

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=.... % and a bunch of other settings]
% all the paths
\end{tikzpicture}
```

To implement clipping, modify this to something like

```
\begin{scope}[x=.... % and a bunch of other settings]
\clip (x1,y1) rectangle (x2,y2);
% all the paths
\end{scope}
```

and in the file where you want to use this, do

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
% all your other stuff
\begin{scope}[shift={(xshift, yshift)}]
\input{drawing.tikz}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

You could also do the `shift`ing in `drawing.tikz`, but it might be easier to have that on the top level. The tedious bit here is working out the coordinates for the clipping path, as well as the shift.

## Possibly more practical

Another route altogether could be to put the diagram in a `\savebox`, and put it in a `\node` to use it, combined with `scope` and `\clip`.

Start by saving the diagram in box box:

```
\newsavebox\Diagram
\savebox{\Diagram}{\input{drawing}} % <-- input file here
```

This is now the unmodified Inkscape output, containing just a `tikzpicture` environment (and possibly colour definitions).
Then get the width and height of the box, and save them in lengths.

```
\newlength\DiagramWd
\newlength\DiagramHt
\setlength\DiagramWd{\wd\Diagram}
\setlength\DiagramHt{\ht\Diagram}
```

Now in your diagram you start a scope, and `shift` it to the appropriate place:

```
\begin{scope}[shift={(0,-7)}]
```

Then make a clipping path based on the size of the box.

```
\clip (0.8\DiagramWd,0) rectangle (\DiagramWd,\DiagramHt);
```

The node must be placed so that the bottom left corner of the box is at (0,0):

```
\node [above right,inner sep=0] at (0,0) {\usebox\Diagram};
\end{scope}
```

The only tedious part here could be working out the appropriate `shift` for the `scope`.

Complete code with example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newsavebox\Diagram
\savebox{\Diagram}{\input{drawing}} % <-- input file here
\newlength\DiagramWd
\newlength\DiagramHt
\setlength\DiagramWd{\wd\Diagram}
\setlength\DiagramHt{\ht\Diagram}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[name=a,inner sep=0,above right]  {\usebox\Diagram};

\draw ($(a.south west)!0.8!(a.south east)$) rectangle (a.north east);
\draw [stealth-] ($(a.south west)!0.8!(a.south east)$) -- ++(-2,-1)
      node[left] (t) {This box indicates the rightmost 20\%};

\begin{scope}[shift={(0,-7)}]
\clip (0.8\DiagramWd,0) rectangle (\DiagramWd,\DiagramHt);
\node [above right,inner sep=0] at (0,0) {\usebox\Diagram};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and sorry because I wast not connected to this website from two days ago. I would like to know if the second method will save the absolute line widths and nodes fonts in the original tikzpicture or scale them?  Otherwise, I would prefer to use your first method, and copy the original tikzpicture in a new .tikz file and add the clip command, then import it using includegraphics and tikzscale package.

Comment: @BxlAdil Don’t think any scaling happens, but just try and you’ll see.